# Im trying to render an object in a row but one of my images doesn't play nice with the others using flexDirection:row

Tags: react-native

Im trying to make this view with a bubble image in the margin between the left of the screen and the larger square images like the picture below

[image: first pic]

but my bubble will not stay in line with the view and 
I get this

[image: second]

`

```
const Recipe = ({ name, durationLabel, numberOfServings, handlePress, handlePush }) => (
  <View styles={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={handlePush}>
      <View syle={{ justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <Image
          source={require("app/assets/icons/bubbleOff.png")}
          style={{justifyContent:'center'}}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={handlePress}>
    <View style={styles.recipeTile}>
      <Image
        source={require("app/assets/cheesecake.png")}
        style={styles.recipeImage}
      />
      <View style={styles.recipeInfo}>
        <View style={styles.recipeNameRow}>
          <Text style={styles.recipeName}>{name}</Text>
          <Image
            style={{ marginRight: 10 }}
            source={require("app/assets/icons/heart.png")}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.recipeStatsRow}>
          <Text style={styles.recipeStats}>
            {durationLabel}
            {' '}
            | Serves
            {' '}
            {numberOfServings}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
);`

my styles 
`
recipeTile: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flex: 1,
    margin: 10,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    marginLeft:60,
  },
  recipeImage: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  },`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `justifyContent: 'center'` and `alignItems: 'center'` to align the image center.

[image]

```
const Recipe = ({
  name,
  durationLabel,
  numberOfServings,
  handlePress,
  handlePush,
}) => (
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={handlePush}>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 0, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5 }}>
        <Image
          source={require('assets/bubbleOff.png')}
          style={{ height: 20, width: 20 }}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FFF' }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 0 }}>
          <Image
            source={require('assets/cheesecake.png')}
            style={styles.recipeImage}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text style={styles.recipeName}>{name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.recipeStats}>
            {durationLabel} | Serves {numberOfServings}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Image
          style={{
            marginRight: 10,
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
            position: 'absolute',
            right: -20,
            top: 30,
          }}
          source={require('assets/heart.png')}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
);
```

[Working demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/simple-card)

Comment: The problem im having is, I need 2 touchable highlights, one for the bubble image and one for the other image.

Comment: just surround those images with touchable highlights.

Comment: you want to remove touchable highlights from the card and add them to the images?

Comment: yea the card is one highlight that navigates to one place and the bubble is a separate highlight, but attached to each card